# JSONException: Misplaced object

Tags: java, gwt, json

This is my code:

```
    JSONStringer result = new JSONStringer();

    for (long i = start; i <= end; i = i + day) {
        ttm.put("$gte", "" + i);
        ttm.put("$lte", "" + (i + day));
        //code code code

        int count = statisticCollection.find(query).count();

        try {
            result.object().key("ttm").value(i).key("count").value(count);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        result.endObject();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I then get a JSONException. I also tried creating and ending the object with a different try-catch block, as below:

```
    JSONStringer result = new JSONStringer();

    try {
        result.object();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (long i = start; i <= end; i = i + day) {
        ttm.put("$gte", "" + i);
        ttm.put("$lte", "" + (i + day));

        //code code code

        long count = statisticCollection.find(query).count();

        try {
            result.key("ttm").value(i).key("count").value(count);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        result.endObject();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and creating and ending the JSONStringer in the for loop itself, as follows:

```
JSONStringer result = new JSONStringer();

for (long i = start; i <= end; i = i + day) {
    ttm.put("$gte", "" + i);
    ttm.put("$lte", "" + (i + day));
    //code code code

    int count = statisticCollection.find(query).count();

try {
     result.object().key("ttm").value(i).key("count").value(count).endObject();
} catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The exception message (and possibly the line number) would hopefully be useful in working out what the problem is.  Right now it does give more context than "something went wrong" (which was already clear from your question).

Comment: The trace is pasted here: http://pastebin.ca/1991983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an array:

```
JSONStringer result = new JSONStringer();
JSONWriter array = result.array();

for (long i = start; i <= end; i = i + day) {
    ttm.put("$gte", "" + i);
    ttm.put("$lte", "" + (i + day));
    //code code code

    int count = statisticCollection.find(query).count();

    try {
        array.object().key("ttm").value(i).key("count").value(count).endObject();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

try {
    array.endArray();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: wow, that worked! could you tell me what I was doing wrong? I see you added a JSONWriter.